# How to programmatically suspend app?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

How to programmatically suspend app?

`App.Current.Exit()` closes the app, but how to suspend?

[Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465088.aspx) does not suggest a way to do this programmatically and I haven't been able to find any documentation on how to suspend the app other than ALT+F4, right-click close from task bar, or minimizing app.

Comment: @SpencerRuport - this is a windows store app, not a forms app.

Comment: @MethodMan - please read the tags, suspend and resume is a very common task for a windows store app.

Comment: have found an answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way for an app to programmatically suspend itself. You can try launching a file or protocol into another app. That may end up switching fully from your app to the other and suspending yours, but there's no guarantee.

If you're trying to control suspension of another app similar to how Visual Studio does when debugging then take a look at the 
[IPackageDebugSettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh707031(v=vs.85).aspx) interface.

Why do you want to do this? What problem are you really trying to solve?

Comment: The requirement is to have a "power off button" in the app that shuts the app down.  According to what I have read App.Current.Exit() is not a graceful way to do that.  Being able to call suspend would allow the app to handling the suspending event and save state.

Comment: The guidelines would be not to have a power off button but to let the system manage the app lifecycle (the user will still have the close button if needed). That said, if you need a power off button then Application.Exit is the right way to programmatically exit the app.

Comment: @Rob: How do I launch a file or protocol into another app?